# Boost: How to check text file character encoding/charset?

Tags: c++, file, boost, text, character-encoding

I wonder hoe to get character encoding/charset from text file with boost? Is it anywhere in boost::locale or boost::filesystem?

Comment: If there is no special marker in the text file (like the UTF8 BOM) then there is no way of knowing. You can try to deduce it by looking for special characters in the file.

Comment: What's the connection between file encoding and filesystem? And no.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing in Boost for this, you need to test is yourself. Algorithm in pseudocode:

```
if BOM present:
  use encoding specified by BOM
else:
  try:
    use UTF-8
  except:
    use ANSI # But only on Windows
```